# Maximum number of concurrent connections possible in BlazeDS

Tags: apache-flex, ria, blazeds

What is the maximum number of concurrent connections possible in BlazeDS using only remoting service

Answer (score 2):

Remoting calls are simple HTTP POST calls...every remote call is going to be executed on one of the application server threads. So the maximum number of concurrent connection will depends on your server configuration (the thread pool size).

Comment: For more information that confirms this, see: http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/2008/02/04/blazeds-and-lcds-performace-difference/

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you mean by remoting, the http proxy? There is a place to set max connections and max connections per client in the proxy-config.xml file. There may also be issues for the BlazeDS if you're using data push, not just the max number of threads, but there are OS settings that may come into question as well, like max number of FDs that can be opened.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is no messaging and data push. Only invoking some java methods from flex. I read in some of the documentations that the maximum number of connections possible in blazeDS is in 100s and in LCDS it is in 1000s. But no exact figure. I have a project where around 1500 users are there. Will it be a problem if we use BlazeDS in this?

Comment: It gets more difficult with the long connection time of push, but really you need to worry about simultaneous connections. So I guess it depends on what sort of app you're building, if all 1500 users are likely to be making connections at exactly the same time, or the requests are slow, you might run into problems. But we've got a couple hundred users, and we use push, so 2 connections per user, and some of the very intense with no problems. YMMV.

Comment: Manoj, I think this were some kind of recommendation not an official statement from Adobe. Regarding your problem 1500 is a low number, but I recommend that you invest some time in learning about server thread pools,server monitoring, thread stack size and maybe a RIA test framework for performance tests.

Comment: Mezmo, are you using HTTP streaming? Only in this case you have 2 connections per user.

Comment: I'm using long-poll amf for stuff I'm pushing from the server, I'm also got a regular amf channel that is used for regular client communication. And we have a corporate policy to use IE 6, suffice it to say, I've triple checked, we are getting 2 connections per user if they are doing an interactive operation.